# Switch Test if isNan

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

In a switch statement, I want make sure the user did not type a number.  I get an error with this: 
"case !isNaN(user):"

```
var user = prompt("Hey! What do you like?","").toLowerCase();
switch(user){
    case "": 
    console.log("Can\'t be blank!");
    break;
    case !isNaN(user):
    console.log("Can\'t be a number");
    break;
    case "food":
    console.log("Food does a body good...sometimes");
    break;
    default:
    console.log("Mmm....Can\'t Make heads or tales of this one.");
}
```

I tried this too, but not working:

```
switch(!isNaN(user)){
    case true:
    console.log("Hey! Can\'t be a number!");
    break;
```

I can get !isNaN to work in an else if, but not in a switch.

```
var user = prompt("Hey! What do you like?","").toLowerCase();
    if(!isNaN(user)){
        console.log("Can\'t be a Number!");
    }
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript is the language

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` statement is comparing your `user` variable to each case.  so it has to be read like

- does user == "". Yes? do stuff
- does user == "food". Yes? do stuff
- otherwise, do stuff

when you read a case statement like this, you'll realise why your NaN case doesn't work

- does user == isNaN(user) <- will never be true

Your final code is the way you need to do it

```
var user = prompt("Hey! What do you like?","").toLowerCase();
if(!isNaN(user)){
    console.log("Can\'t be a Number!");
}
```

Comment: good tips!  But how do you do that in a switch? it works for the final code: an IF/IF ELSE, but is there an equivalent for a SWITCH?.

Comment: @ryanjohnsond Actually you're goal is to cross-breed a cat with a dog.

Comment: You can't check to see if a input from a prompt is a number?

Comment: @ryanjohnsond You can, but switch is not the right tool for it. You're trying to bang in a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: Meant to say, "You can't use a switch statement in JavaScript to check to see if a input from a prompt is a number?"

Comment: @ryanjohnsond the approach I would use would be something like `if(!IsNaN(user)) { /* no numbers */ } else { /* switch statement */ }`

Comment: Cool. Didn't know I could do that, let alone, even think of that. Thnx!